# Model property not found when executing Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble trying to get a property of a model from a SQL server database. I have defined the property on my model but when I do a Linq query, it doesn't let me get that property.

This is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProgramaAlimenticio.Models
{
    public class RutaMD
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual int pk_ruta { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ruta")]
        public virtual string nombre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Proveedor")]
        public virtual Nullable<int> fk_proveedor { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Programa")]
        public virtual int fk_programa { get; set; }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(RutaMD))]
    public partial class Ruta {  }
}
```

The property that is not available is fk_programa.

When I do the next query the problem happens:

```
var programas = from r in db.Ruta
                join p in db.Programa on r.fk_programa equals p.pk_programa
                into o
                select o;
```

Comment: What is "the problem"? Is an exception occurring? What is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `db.Ruta` has `Ruta` items in it, instead of `RutaMD` items, then it appears your `Ruta` class doesn't have an `fk_programa` property on it.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RutaMD))]
public partial class Ruta {  }
```

Maybe this property is supposed to be in the other half of the partial class: have you double-checked that it's actually there? And that it's public? And that the name is the same? And that it has a `get`ter? And that the `get`ter is public?